# What's the Big O run time of the two following solutions

Tags: php, big-o

I came up with 2 solutions for the following interview question

```
Given 2 different lists of integers, write a function that will return their intersection.
```

**Solution 1:**
With the following code below I sort both lists, then traverse them with 2 counters (one per list). Increment the pointer that points at the smaller value. If both pointers point at the same value, insert it into the result and increment both pointers. (Returns sorted intersections)

```
<?php

    function find_intersection($a1, $a2) {

        $intersection = array();
        sort($a1);
        sort($a2);

        $i = $j = 0;
        while($i < count($a1) && $j < count($a2)) {
            if($a1[$i] > $a2[$j]) {
                $j++;
            } else if($a1[$i] < $a2[$j]) {
                $i++;
            } else {
                $intersection[] = $a1[$i];
                $i++;
                $j++;
            }
        }
        return $intersection;
    }
?>
```

**Solution 2:**
    Here I iterate the first list, put the values into a array, using the value as the key, and the count as the value (if
    it’s already in the list increment count by one, else insert a count of 1). Then iterate list2, if the value is in the
    hashtable and > 0 insert that value into the result array, decrementing the value in the hash table.

Below solution 2 will return UNSORTED intersection

```
function find_intersection2($a1, $a2) {
        $hash_arr = array();
        $intersection = array();
        for($i = 0; $i < count($a1); $i++) {
            if(isset($hash_arr[$a1[$i]])) {
                $hash_arr[$a1[$i]]++;
            } else {
                $hash_arr[$a1[$i]] = 1;
            }
        }

        for($j = 0; $j < count($a2); $j++) {
            if(isset($hash_arr[$a2[$j]])) {
                $intersection[] = $a2[$j];
                $hash_arr[$a2[$j]]--;
            }
        }

        return $intersection;
    }
```

**Question 1)**
What would be the runtime of Solution #1? Is it O(n log n) due to a sort? How would you analyze it? Explain it please.

**Question 2)**
For solution #1, if I knew for sure that the arrays I will receive will be sorted and wouldn't need to sort them, would the solution be O(n) then because of while loop iteration?

**Question 3)** 
For solution 2, is it Big O(n) because I am running 2 separate loops?

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: @CommuSoft No this is not for homework. Tried? I have coded out all the solutions and posted the source code. I am just wondering about Big O notation to see which solution is faster..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Question 1

In the solution two you have

1. `Sort`
2. `Sort`
3. `Single loop`

The complexity of the loop is O(n), so we have to look at the sort. [According to PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php), it uses Quicksort, so the complexity is O(n log n)

> Note: Like most PHP sorting functions, sort() uses an implementation of » Quicksort.

Therefore, we have O(n log n) + O(n log n) + O(n). We take the bigger which is **O(n log n)**.

## Question 2

In that case you could remove the `sort` calls, and it would be O(n). If you keep them, it will continue being O(n log n).

## Question 3

Yes, the complexity is O(n) + O(n), so the final complexity is O(n) as you said.